# Back button issue when alert or ion-select is present

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to close alert when the alert is present with back key press, else the page will be navigated to another page. I've tried `alert.dismiss()` in `ionViewDidLeave` & `WillLeave` but its not triggering in the back button.It's navigating back page still alert or ion-select options are present in the other page.Please help me to come out from this problem.

Comment: can you show your code then there will be chance to find whats the problem

Comment: @AbineshJoyel please update your code

Comment: @Utpaul why are you asking to me

Comment: @Utpaul I did't ask the question please see who ask it

Comment: @AbineshJoyel first of all are you want any help or not ? if you want any help then update your question any give us your code where its given error...

Comment: @AbineshJoyel check it i will solve it ......

Comment: @AbineshJoyel now check.. and give me feedback